# Power BI - Date Format

Tags: date, powerbi, formatting

I'm attempting to change the date format of a column from **01 Jan 2021** to **01 Jan 21** but it looks like that's not one of the formats available in power Bi. Is there a formula that might do this for me?

Kind regards,
Cian

Comment: Shouldn't be 01 Jan 21?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is possible to do what you want without using any formula.
First, go to the Model View and select the desired column. In my case is Date2. Then open the Properties tab that is at the left.

[image]

Now, go to Formatting, select Custom and at the Custom format textbox paste d MMM yy

[image]

By doing that you should get the expected result.